# Is it possible to automate creation of keyfile, csc and regasm on client PC?

Tags: javascript, com, activex, .net-assembly, assembly-signing

we have created an assembly dll that can be called via javascript and this opens up an exe applicaiton. Inorder for it to run, we have to:-

- Ship the .cs file to customer
- Provide batch file containing:-
- Create the DLL from CS ---> Run C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe 
  /t:library myclass.cs
- Create a new key file ---> Go to C:\program files x86\micorsoft 
  SDKs\windows\v8.0\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn -k mynewkey.snk
- Sign the DLL using the key file ---> C:\program files x86\micorsoft 
  SDKs\windows\v8.0\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn -R AClass.dll myneykey.snk
- Register the signed DLL ---> regasm AClass.dll/tlb /codebase.

This has to be executed by each customer. Is there any way to automate this, via javascript on the browser itself.. It is OK if the signing part is skipped..

Comment: Is there a reason you're not shipping the library in binary form?

Comment: Hi PMF, that would again require users to click and run the binary.. Is there any other workaround for this? One would be to run the binary via some group policy.. is there any other method you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious solution that comes into my mind is to provide an installer that automatically does all of the above. That still needs the user to click something, but its just a single click. I don't think you can automate this, because that would be a major security hole in the browser if it allowed such an installation without user interaction. You can of course configure a browser plugin or an activeX control, which directly installs from the browser. But even that usually requires manual confirmation by the user for security reasons.

Comment: Is there a way to use it without a preinstall.. maybe by setting codebase value.. or by creating an activex object using <object tag>.. Just guessing..

Comment: JavaScript and browser stuff in general are not my domain. So I'm afraid I don't know. Maybe it would help someone if you posted the code how you load the dll?